# Timestamp manipulation of multiple records

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate hours for each user. One user can check in and check out multiple times per day.

Beside events CHECK IN and CHECK OUT, I have two more (BUSINESS and PRIVATE).

If a user has an event BUSINESS between between last CHECK OUT and last CHECK IN for the same day, time between last CHECK OUT and CHECK IN would be considered as working hours.

If he has a BUSINESS event as last record after CHECK OUT, it will calculate hours (CHECK OUT time - CHECK IN + BUSINESS = 8).

In table I have place where I record events for each user.

CASE 1

```
ID       USERID             TIME               COMMAND

1         1          2016-11-29 08:00:00       CHECK_IN
2         1          2016-11-29 10:05:14       CHECK_OUT
3         1          2016-11-29 12:22:14       BUSINESS
4         1          2016-11-29 13:32:14       CHECK_IN
5         1          2016-11-29 16:00:00       CHECK_OUT
```

According to table above I should get that user has total 8 working hours for specific day.

CASE 2

```
ID       USERID             TIME               COMMAND

1         1          2016-11-29 08:00:00       CHECK_IN
2         1          2016-11-29 10:05:14       CHECK_OUT
3         1          2016-11-29 12:22:14       PRIVATE
4         1          2016-11-29 13:32:14       CHECK_IN
5         1          2016-11-29 16:00:00       CHECK_OUT
```

In the case above time between last checkout (ID 2) and Last check in (ID 3) does not count in working hours.

I am trying to make script to calculate working hours for each employee for each day in month.

I am having trouble on how to subtract CHECK_OUT time with the closest CHECK_IN, that problem occurs when user has multiple records for one day.

Comment: Is there always either a "BUSINESS" or "PRIVATE" entry between a "CHECK_OUT" entry and the following "CHECK_IN" entry?

Comment: It can be BUSINESS or PRIVATE whole day, if is business then user will receive 8 hours for that day if PRIVATE user will get 0 hours for that day. But if he leaves work then is always CHECK_OUT entry first and if he comes back to work CHECK_IN. But can have more business entries per one day

Comment: There seems to be a lot of logic specific only to your case involved here. You should make an attempt at solving this first, and then ask a specific question when you get stuck on something. Saying "I have no idea where to start", (which is the feeling I get from your question) isn't really a good fit here.

Comment: I am getting problem if I have more records for one user at one day. Just how to substract last check_out from last check_in

Comment: Can you post the code that works if you have only one record per day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working off of the following assumptions:

- Hours worked never cross calendar days
- The first record of the day is always CHECK_IN unless the only record that day is BUSINESS or PRIVATE
- A CHECK_IN record always has a CHECK_OUT record after it with no other record in between a CHECK_IN and the next CHECK_OUT
- There can only be either a BUSINESS record or a PRIVATE record (or neither) in between a CHECK_OUT and the next CHECK_IN. There cannot be both.
- I am ignoring any potential Daylight Savings impacts
- I am assuming that $entries is an array with rows for one user for one day

```
function getTimeWorkedFromEntries($entries)
{
    $timeWorked = 0;
    $lastTimeIn = null;
    $lastTimeOut = null;
    $lastEntry = null;

    // the case where the only entry that day is 'BUSINESS'
    if(count($entries) == 1 && $entries[0]['COMMAND'] == 'BUSINESS')
    {
        $timeWorked = 28800; // 8 hours
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($entries as $timeEntry)
        {
            // first check_in of the day
            if($timeEntry['COMMAND'] == 'CHECK_IN' && is_null($lastTimeOut))
            {
                $lastTimeIn = $timeEntry['TIME'];
            }
            // CHECK_IN following a CHECK_OUT and then a BUSINESS
            else if($timeEntry['COMMAND'] == 'CHECK_IN' && !is_null($lastTimeOut) && $lastEntry['COMMAND'] == 'BUSINESS')
            {
                $timeWorked += (strtotime($timeEntry['TIME']) - strtotime($lastTimeOut));
                $lastTimeIn = $timeEntry['TIME'];
            }
            else if($timeEntry['COMMAND'] == 'CHECK_IN')
            {
                $lastTimeIn = $timeEntry['TIME'];
            }
            // CHECK_OUT that follows a CHECK_IN
            else if($timeEntry['COMMAND'] == 'CHECK_OUT')
            {
                $timeWorked += (strtotime($timeEntry['TIME']) - strtotime($lastTimeIn));
                $lastTimeOut = $timeEntry['TIME'];
            }

            $lastEntry = $timeEntry;
        }
    }

    return $timeWorked;
}
```

[Live Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebd62d56c99a28a0c870c8a1f860bd81848899cb)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. It works this way, but when I use this to count hours for each user and for each day in month It does not count well. I made a script which checks if user is checked for a specific day. That script works well, now I wanted to display how many hours he performed for that day